# Select2 version4 execute a callback function in focus event

Tags: jquery-select2-4

I am looking for a way to execute a callback function when the element get focused in select2 Jquery.
This was supported in older version. It was like this:

`.on("select2-focus", function(e) { log ("focus");})`

But in the last version they deleted based on this link [version 4](https://gemnasium.com/bower/select2/versions/4.0.0-beta.2) is delete it and the reason was: **select2-focus - Use the native focus event instead** but how can I execute a callback when the event focus is fired ?
I took a look at other questions related to this topic but there were no solution for this specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$('select').on('select2:open', function(e) {
    // do something
});
```

Everything described here: https://select2.github.io/options.html#events-public

Comment: I am looking for a way to execute a callback function when the element get focused, not to execute a function when the select2 is opened.

Comment: @SadokMtir Have you tried $(document).on('focus', '.select2-selection--single', function(e) {  var select2_open = $(this).parent().parent().siblings('select'); ?